# How to update identity data from membership

Tags: c#, sql, model-view-controller, asp.net-identity, asp.net-membership

I have a Database that has Both the standard asp.net-membership and the asp.net-identity tables.

If i modify a user in my MVC4 website it will only change the membership tabels
So Is ther like a standard script that will update all the identity tables based on the memberschip tables ?

[the Membership And Identity tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJJYK.png)

Comment: And your problem is...?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand weel your question, you ask how to update something in SQL data base. For me, I use the UPDATE.

```
Sqlcon.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = Sqlcon.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE 'TABLE' Set 'COLUMN' NAME WHERE 'COLUMN NAME'" + NewPassword + "';";

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            Sqlcon.Close();
```

I hope it is can help you.
Bye.

Comment: Nice way of leaving yourself open to Sql Injection